# How to fix : System services not available to Activities before onCreate()?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am making an android app that can send notifications even if the app is closed. So I added a NotificationService to call when the app is destroyed. But I get an error: System services not available to Activities before onCreate() when I force the app to stop.

This is the MainActivity.java:

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button1;
    private Button button2;
    private Button button3;
    private Button button4;

    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "telus";
    private static final String CHANNEL_NAME = "telus app";
    private static final String CHANNEL_DESC = "telus app notification";

    private int count = 1;
    Timer timer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        openActivity_web();
    }

    });
        button2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openActivationPage();
            }
        });
        button3=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openMysql();
            }
        });

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            channel.setDescription(CHANNEL_DESC);
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

        }



        findViewById(R.id.button4).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                displayNotification();

            }

        });

        class sendnotif extends TimerTask {
            public void run() {

                displayNotification();
            }
        }


        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new sendnotif(), 0, 5000);

}

    public void displayNotification(){
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm)
                        .setContentTitle("Titre de la notification")
                        .setContentText("C'est le text de la notification")
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                ;

        NotificationManagerCompat mNotifMgr = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        mNotifMgr.notify( 1, mBuilder.build());

    }

    public void openActivity_web(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebPage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
}
    public void openActivationPage(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivationPage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void openMysql(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, mysql_display.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        startService(new Intent(this, NotificationService.class));

    }

}
```

and this is the NotificationService.java:

```js
public class NotificationService extends Service {

    Timer timer;
    TimerTask timerTask;
    String TAG = "Timers";
    int Your_X_SECS = 5;



    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        startTimer();

        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
        stoptimertask();
        super.onDestroy();


    }

    //we are going to use a handler to be able to run in our TimerTask
    final Handler handler = new Handler();


    public void startTimer() {
        //set a new Timer
        timer = new Timer();

        //initialize the TimerTask's job
        initializeTimerTask();

        //schedule the timer, after the first 5000ms the TimerTask will run every 10000ms
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000, Your_X_SECS * 1000); //
        //timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000,1000); //
    }

    public void stoptimertask() {
        //stop the timer, if it's not already null
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }
    }

    public void initializeTimerTask() {

        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                //use a handler to run a toast that shows the current timestamp
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        MainActivity notif = new MainActivity();
                        notif.displayNotification();


                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This is the error log when I try to manually stop the app:

```js
2019 - 07 - 16 20: 10: 23.079 23334 - 23334 / com.example.testapp E / AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.testapp, PID: 23334
java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java: 5581)
at androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat. < init > (NotificationManagerCompat.java: 158)
at androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat.from(NotificationManagerCompat.java: 153)
at com.example.testapp.MainActivity.displayNotification(MainActivity.java: 103)
at com.example.testapp.NotificationService$1$1.run(NotificationService.java: 89)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java: 751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 756)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you mean that your activity is destroyed, the activity can no longer be used to show notifications. The error message assumes that you are trying to show notifications too early; in your case, my guess is that you are trying to show notifications too late.

Comment: `MainActivity notif = new MainActivity()` this won't work; use an `Intent` and `startActivity()` to correctly set up activities.

Comment: but I don't want to start an activity, I just want to send notification using this function displayNotification()