# How to start NotificationListenerService in background mode?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using the `onNotificationPosted` method with `NotificationListenerService` but if I close the program method and the class stops working. What needs to be done so that the program can process notifications even if you close the program.

```java
public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return super.onBind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("onCreate", "Inside on create");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted (StatusBarNotification sbn){

}
```

Comment: Try using the code from this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57064248/how-to-fix-system-services-not-available-to-activities-before-oncreate